# Draw Networkx : how to draw one particular label?

Tags: python, label, networkx, box, edges

I use Networkx on python 2.7 to represent and simulate financial flow in projects.

I have 4 labels for each edge, so when I print them on the graph, I can't barely read anything.

For example :

```
import networkx as nx
H=nx.Graph()
t_op=[437,325,60,633,2156,3029, 1973,151, 375]
arcs_H=[("Habitants", "Collectivites"), ("Activites", "Collectivites")]
H.add_edges_from(arcs_H)

H["Activites"]["Collectivites"]['weight']=t_op[7]
H["Activites"]["Collectivites"]['nature']="tva_logement"
H["Activites"]["Collectivites"]['vers']="Collectivites"
H["Activites"]["Collectivites"]['label']="Public"

H["Habitants"]["Collectivites"]['weight']=t_op[8]
H["Habitants"]["Collectivites"]['nature']="tva_bureaux"
H["Habitants"]["Collectivites"]['vers']="Collectivites"
H["Habitants"]["Collectivites"]['label']="Public"


pos=nx.spring_layout(H)               
nx.draw(H, pos, with_labels=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(H, pos, edge_labels=None, label_pos=0.5, font_size=10, font_color='k', font_family='serif', font_weight='normal', alpha=1.0, bbox=dict(facecolor='red', alpha=0.5), horizontalalignment='center', rotate=True)
plt.show()
```

How could I manage to create box with defined height and width above my edges ?

Thank you,

Sophie

Comment: If you don't want to use `draw_networkx_edge_labels`, you can always use `matplotlib.pyplot.annotate` to add text boxes at defined places. You can find the midpoint of the edge by taking the mean of the positions of the endpoints of the edge.